# Block audio and video playback in the browser in the background

Tags: chrome-for-android, xiaomi

**Prehistory**:
On the phone (**android, xiaomi**) of the child, "Google Family Link" is installed with a time limit for using applications (when the screen is on). But the child turns on an audiobook or video and turns on the screen lock - the media plays in the background and the time of using the phone does not increase.

**Question**: How to block media browser playback with a locked screen?

I did not find a solution in *chrome://flag* and *phone settings (sounds, battery)*.
Turning off the sound in the tabs is also not an option (it's easy to turn it back).

Maybe I missed something and was looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Have you tried to block/restrict those media apps via https://support.google.com/android/answer/9346420?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the settings for the apps themselves. From your device settings to apps. Select your app. Find the battery usage Setting. In there you will be able to optimize battery usage. There should be an option to restrict or allow the app to continue running.